# Why I am always getting 0 as the minimum of an array

Tags: c, minimum, minmax

Below is my code for finding the minimum and maximum value from an array. Can anyone explain why I am getting 0 as the output for minimum element? What can be the reason behind it?

I am getting the maximum value among the elements of array as desired.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 3

int a[N],min,max, max1,min1;
void minmax(int m,int n);

void minmax(int m, int n){
    if(m==n){
        max=min=a[m];
        return;
    }

    if(m == n-1){
        if(a[m]>a[n]){
            max= a[m];
            min = a[n];

        }
        else{
            max= a[n];
            min = a[m];
        }
    }
    else{

        int mid = (m+n)/2;

        minmax(1,mid);
        max1=max;
        min1=min;
        minmax(mid+1,n);
    }

    if(max1>max){
        max= max1;
    }

    if(min1<min){
        min=min1;
    }


}

int main(){

    int i,j,k;
    printf("Enter array\n");
    for(i=1;i<=N;i++)   //input
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);

    minmax(1,N);

    printf("%d %d",max,min);

}
```

Comment: `for(i=1;i<=N;i++)` --> `for(i=0;i<N;i++)` C is 0 origin.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly, this is impossible to read.

Comment: `a[3]` does not exist; `a[0]` has not been set.

Comment: Your recursive approach is broken; `min` and `max` are global variables, but you use them like they were local...

Answer (score 0):

- In your `minmax` function, you return from the call when `m==n`
- But do you know the values of m and n when it reaches that? One of
  the values include `m=n=0`.

Firstly, your `for` loop takes an array from `index=1 till N`. If you do so, make sure you make the necessary changes in `minmax`function also.

So, the simplest fix (just saw mentioned in comments also) is:

Change `for(i=1;i<=N;i++)` to `for(i=0;i<N;i++)`